# while loop won't register any other user input besides the first and last

Tags: python

Trying to have the while loop read the selection but the program only reads the first one for square and 5 to close the program, what do I need to change in order for it to actually read it the values 2,3 and 4 so I can add the other functions for the areas? I've tried
it with elif and else but when I add that it won't even read the selection

```
def square(l):
    area = l*l
    return area

def rectangle(l,w):
    area = l*w
    return area

def triangle(b,h):
#b: base , h: height 
    b = int(input('Enter the Base of your Triangle: '))
    h = int(input('Enter the Height of your Triangle'))
    area = (b * h)/2 
    print('Area of the Triangle= ' +str(area))
    
print ("Choose which shape whos area you would like to find:")
print ("1 = Square")
print ("2 = Rectangle")
print ("3 = Triangle")
print ("4 = circle")
print ("Enter Option:  ")
    
user_input = 0

while user_input not in (1,5) :
    
    user_input = int(input("Enter your Choice: "))

#--------------------------------------------------------------
if (user_input == 1):
    print ("You've selected area of a Square")
    length = int(input("Enter the length of a side from your square: "))
    area = square(length)
    print("Area of your Square is: ", area)
    
#--------------------------------------------------------------
if (user_input == 2):
    print ("You've selected area of a Rectangle")
    length = int(input("Enter the length of your rectangle: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width of your rectangle: "))
    area = rectangle(length,width)
    print("Area of your rectangle is: ", area)
```

Comment: Typo.  You want `while user_input not in (1,2,3,4,5):`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line of code:

```
while user_input not in (1, 5):
```

This is checking for exactly what you say the code seems to be checking for, just either `1` or `5`.  This is the case because `(1, 5`) creates a tuple containing the numbers `1` and `5`.  This line therefore is testing if `user_input` is one of those two values.

I think what you meant to do is this instead:

```
while user_input not in range(1, 6):
```

You have to use `6` rather than `5` because the second argument to `range()` is not included in the resulting range.  So `range(1, 5)` would produce the equivalent of the tuple `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: I see, I didn't understand why it wasn't reading it in, I completely forgot about range(). Thank you